# How do I use the if statement to determen if the script should change the DNS-settings?

Tags: powershell

My PC is going to change between DNS-servers a lot and I don't want to do it manualy everytime. Therefore I want to create a PowerShell script that changes the DNS-adress from adress nr1 to nr2 if im currently using nr1  and the other way around.

I can't figure out how to write the Boolean expression to get the script to change to DNS2 if I'm using DNS1

```
if( ) {
   Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 6 -ServerAddresses $dns1
} else {
   Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 6 -ServerAddresses $dns2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `if()` statement, you need to add a condition to check against... So, do something like this:

```bsh
if((Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 10 -AddressFamily IPv4) -match $dns1) {
    # Do some thing
}
else {
    # Do some other thing
}
```

Just make sure to change your InterfaceIndex to something that's relevant to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle between your defined `$dns1` and `$dns2` ServerAddresses

```
$dns1 = '192.168.0.x'  # or whatever
$dns2 = '192.168.0.y'
if((Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 6).ServerAddresses -contains $dns2) {
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 6 -ServerAddresses $dns1
} else {
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 6 -ServerAddresses $dns2
}
```